# Как переслать сообщение в aiogram 3?

Tags: python, aiogram, aiogram-3.x

Есть декоратор, который получает фотографию, когда находится в состоянии Buy_item.

Как реализовать пересылку сообщения, которое пришлет пользователь, мне?

Исходный код:

```
@router.message(Buy_item.check and F.photo)
async def verify_buy (message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    #Пересылка сообщения другому человеку (по user_id указанному заранее)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У message есть метод send_copy:

```
await message.send_copy(chat_id=user_id)
```

В `user_id` нужно указать ID пользователя/группы куда будет сообщение пересылаться